# method to unblock "hold" using for loop?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, anylogic

I am using AnyLogic to simualte.

I want to check if each queue ( queues from 1 to 10 ) contains agent or not.

if it contains, unblock the hold that is linked to the queue, if not keep it block.

I am using LinkedList to access each queue and hold:

my code:

```java
LinkedList holds = new LinkedList();
holds.add(VIP_Female_Hold);
holds.add(VIP_Male_Hold);
holds.add(FT_Appoin_Female_Hold);
holds.add(FT_Walkin_Female_Hold);
holds.add(Stand_Appoin_Female_Hold);
holds.add(Group_Appoint_Female_Hold);
holds.add(Stand_Walkin_Female_Hold);
holds.add(Group_Appoint_Male_Hold);
holds.add(FT_Appoint_Male_Hold);
holds.add(Stand_Appoint_Male_Hold);
holds.add(FT_Walkin_Male_Hold);
holds.add(Stand_Walkin_Male_Hold);
holds.add(Determination_Hold);

LinkedList queues = new LinkedList();
queues.add(VIP_Female_Q);
queues.add(VIP_Male_Q);
queues.add(FT_Appoin_Female_Q);
queues.add(FT_Walkin_Female_Q);
queues.add(Stand_Appoin_Female_Q);
queues.add(Group_Appoint_Female_Q);
queues.add(Stand_Walkin_Female_Q);
queues.add(Group_Appoint_Male_Q);
queues.add(FT_Appoint_Male_Q);
queues.add(Stand_Appoint_Male_Q);
queues.add(FT_Walkin_Male_Q);
queues.add(Stand_Walkin_Male_Q);
queues.add(Determination_Q);


for (int i = 0 ; i < queues.size() ; i++)
{
    if (queues.contains(i) == true)
}
```

I created 1 LinkedList from queues and other LinkedList for hold. I just want to know how to write the unblock statement. I tried

```java
hold(i).unblock();
```

but that did not work.

also I tried to write the code in a function and then write the condition in "Event". it didn`t work

any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

hold(i) would work if hold was a population of agents, but it's not... and your linkedlist is called holds not hold so be careful with the names you choose.

the way you do it is:

```
holds.get(i).unblock();
```

Don't forget to define the objects of your collection appropriately... for instance for the hold collection:
[image: hold collection]

for the queue collection the object type is Queue

Comment: I tried it. it says:The method unblock() is undefined for the type Object.